# interchange html content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Good day! Newbie here. I just want to know if it's possible to change the whole content of an html using javascript? I got some codes here. (not mine but whoever did this, thank you so much!) I don't know where to put/insert all the codes of the new layout like when you click a button then the whole content will change. Thank you very much for helping me.

```
<script language="Javascript">
  <!--
  var newContent='<html><head><script language="Javascript">function Hi()</script></head><body onload="Hi();"><p id="p">hello</p></body></html>';
  function ReplaceContent(NC) {
    document.write(NC);
    document.close();
  }
  function Hi() {
    ReplaceContent(newContent);
  }
  -->
</script>
```

Comment: nobody can/will answer this, it's too much to answer.  You need to try something, and ask a very specific question.

Comment: @jdu there are enough people hungry for internet points. Almost everything will get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with jQuery.

```
    function insertHtml()
    {
         var newHtml = '<div><span>Hello World</span></div>';
         $('body').html(newHtml);


    }
```

Something like that will replace the entire contents of body with newHtml.  You can also do this with pure javascript using the .innerHtml property but jQuery has many advantages.

EDIT:  If you want to add something to the DOM rather than replacing the entire thing, use

```
    $('body').append(newHtml)
```

instead.  This will add the content to the end of the body.  This is very often used for things like adding rows to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but this code is not valid unless you remove the comment tags  however don't use the document.write() after page load unless you want to  overwrite everything in page including the script